# Ubuntu GUI crash when LightDM enters, unable to login

Tags: login, lightdm, gui

This issue happened spounteniously, i don´t know what could have cause it as i wasn´t using the PC when it happened. I ruled out any messing around with the setting as the user doesn´t know how to enter the BIOS, doesn´t have the sudo password and was only using firefox and libreoffice when it happened.

After the plymouth sequence i get this error. [image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uf1xdkqkw9alvcu/IMAG0252.jpg]

And this option: [image]

I follow each option and nothing happens after that. The issue persist after rebooting. I choose the other options to see if anything happens, i either get back to option 1 or doesn´t show anything anormal. (I have pictures i someone wants to know)

What i found weird is that event though the error is possitioned in the chip, however ubuntu 10.04 and 12.04 run fine in a live CD

I saw that some people are having issues when LightDM has a non default wallpaper, but i use a default one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually located in the graphics's driver. 
As you said : " however ubuntu 10.04 and 12.04 run fine in a live CD " I assume that something went wrong with your currently installed (additional) driver.

I will not include every possible solution here (from different graphic cards and drivers).

A suggestion would be to reinstall the driver from recovery mode. Also would be good to try to repair any broken package through the same procedure (recovery mode).

**Following is an example** for Nvidia additional driver. (nvidia-current)

1) Boot as usually but in grub menu select the recovery mode . (If you have no grub menu, hold down [Shift] key during boot until grub menu loaded)

2) At the opened window select "Network" so the network connection established. 
Also this option will make the system Read-Write (and not only read)

3) Next choose "Dpkg - Repair Broken Packages"

4) Next you select ROOT

and you can reinstall nvidia drivers (bellow command depends on what drivers you had install previously)

For nvidia-current

```
apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-current
```

note here that you don't need sudo cuz you are already connected as root.

At the end you can select "resume" and see if your problem fixed.

Good Luck